# r Check if Sys.time() is in a given interval of hours of the day

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I'm looking for a potentially less hacky solution with lubridate (sth. similar) here.

Use case: I'd like to check if `Sys.time()` is in between a given interval of **hours**, which has turned out to be a little more complex than I thought b/c a `datetime` seems to always need a date, e.g. `paste("01-01-01", "9:00 AM")`

So here is what I did to check if `Sys.time()` is in between working hours. I'm extracting the numerical values for the hours and comparing them, which seems hacky to me :)

```
as.numeric(format(lubridate::as_datetime(Sys.time(), tz = "America/New_York"), format = "%H")) >= as.numeric(format(ymd_hm(paste("01-01-01", "9:00 AM"), tz = "America/New_York"), format = "%H")) &

as.numeric(format(lubridate::as_datetime(Sys.time(), tz = "America/New_York"), format = "%H")) < as.numeric(format(ymd_hm(paste("01-01-01", "6:00 PM"), tz = "America/New_York"), format = "%H"))
```

This works and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the set parameters. Again, I'm looking for a more elegant solution to this monstrosity, or maybe this helps somebody who was looking exactly for this.

Any feedback welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `hour`. Identical `tz=` on both LHS and RHS cancel out each other.

```
hour(Sys.time()) %in% 9:18 
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Awesome thanks - yeah that's a lot cleaner! I made one change where I include the `tz = ` on the `Sys.time()` side, since I'm running the script on a server with `UTC`;

`as.numeric(format(lubridate::as_datetime(Sys.time(), tz = "America/New_York"), format = "%H")) %in% 9:18`